# Sending notification to GCM using HTTP POST

Tags: android, http-post, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send an `HTTP POST` notification to Google Cloud Messaging in order for a notification to be delivered to the app that I am developing.

For testing purposes, I am also delivering the `HTTP POST` from the app as well - just to see if I can get a response (will implement this logic server-side later).

I am following the tutorial found [here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html) but it's hard to follow as I am not using `JSON`. When I run the code below, I get the expected response: `Unauthorized: Error 401`. This is because I am not supplying enough data, but cannot seem to discover which data I need to send with this request.

```
class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
    {
        final static String API_KEY = ***********; // From google developer console
        final static String CONTENT_TYPE = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... uri)
        {
            String responseString = "";
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(uri[0]);
            try
            {
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
                // not even sure if "Authorization" is the correct key to send
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Authorization", "key=" + API_KEY));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Content-Type", CONTENT_TYPE));
                HttpEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs);
                post.addHeader(entity.getContentType());
                post.setEntity(entity);

                HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
                String line = "";
                while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    Log.i("HTTP RESPONSE", line);
                    responseString = responseString + "\n" + line;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            return responseString;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, ResponseActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("text", result);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

What must I change in order to successfully send this GCM notification request?

Comment: 401 is not lack of sent data, it's an authorization problem: `Similar to 403 Forbidden, but specifically for use when authentication is required and has failed or has not yet been provided. The response must include a WWW-Authenticate header field containing a challenge applicable to the requested resource. See Basic access authentication and Digest access authentication.`. Are you sure you're running the right URL to post data?

Comment: The URL I'm running is `https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send`, which is apparently the correct one according to http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to what `@Eran` proposed, other possible issue could be setting the `Content-Type` of the HTTP header incorrectly. Try replacing this line:

```
post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

With this one:

```
HttpEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs);
```

Afterwards:

```
post.addHeader(entity.getContentType());
post.setEntity(entity);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I made the changes but still getting an `Unauthorized` 401 error :(

Comment: It's odd, seems this is an authentication error. The troubleshoot points here http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html#auth_error Have you checked whether everything is ok?

Answer (score 0):

Here's your error :

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Authorization", API_KEY));
```

It should be :

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Authorization", "key="+API_KEY));
```

> The HTTP header must contain the following headers:
>
> ```
> Authorization: key=YOUR_API_KEY
> Content-Type: application/json for JSON; application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8 for plain text.
> ```

Comment: Thanks, I tried making that change but still the same response. :(

Comment: @Teifi In that case there may be a problem with your API key. Have you specified white listed IPs for it, or have you left the IP list empty?

Comment: On the official documentation, it said that using `0.0.0.0/0` can be used for testing purposes, so that's the one I've been using. Am I correct in thinking this allows the request to come from any IP?

Comment: @Teifi I'm not sure about that. Why don't you just leave it empty?